# Detect if the first letter of each word is in capital letters

Tags: r, regex, string, uppercase

I am trying to detect whether first letter of each word in the given string is in caps or not.

I have problem like this

```
x <- c("Bachelor of Technology - Computers + Bachelor of Technology - Science",
       "Hello Sam ,How Are You?", "Certificate - Internet and Web Technology")
```

I am expecting output as

```
FALSE,TRUE,FALSE
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about checking for the opposite (word boundary followed by a lower case letter) and negating the result?

```
!grepl("\\b(?=[a-z])", x, perl = TRUE)
#[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

If you only want to consider the words that come after a space-character, you can adjust it to:

```
!grepl("\\s+[a-z]", x)
```

Comment: `!grepl("\\b[a-z]", x,)`

Comment: thank you very much your valuable answer but I am facing another problem in this like when I have a string which consist of some punctuation like comma(,) or (.) then it is giving FALSE as result but I want TRUE in that case like    x <- c("Bachelor of Technology - Computers + Bachelor of Technology - Science",
       "Hello Sam ,How Are You?", "Certificate - Internet and Web Technology","Langara Colle.g,e")  Its giving FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE but I want FALSE  TRUE FALSE TRUE

Comment: @girijesh96, I added an alternative that only considers characters after spaces.

Comment: can you please tell me from where I can learn these things in great details.Thank You

Comment: @girijesh96, you can just google for some regex introduction / tutorial. For example, you can also look at https://regexr.com/ and test your own patterns with explanation

Answer (score 2):

Here is a non-regex approach,

```
sapply(strsplit(x, '[[:punct:]]|\\s+'), function(i){i1 <- substr(trimws(i), 1, 1); 
                                              all(i1[i1 != ''] == toupper(i1[i1 != '']))})

#[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

If you want to add/remove delimiters you can do it in the argument of `strsplit`

Answer (score 1):

Here a solution using some more details if you need them.

```
library(stringi)
#split string into its single elements but maintain all elements
#by using lookaround regex
x_split <- stri_split_regex(x, "(?=\\b)")
#check each element in uppercase
upper_check <- lapply(x_split, function(x) stri_detect_regex(x, "^\\p{Lu}"))
#combine the information
#(all steps might of course be done in a single call,
#just separated the steps here for demonstration)
mapply(function(x,y) rbind(string = x, start_w_upper = y), x_split, upper_check)
# [[1]]
#              [,1]    [,2]       [,3]    [,4]    [,5]    [,6]         [,7]    [,8]        [,9]    [,10]      [,11]  
# string        ""      "Bachelor" " "     "of"    " "     "Technology" " - "   "Computers" " + "   "Bachelor" " "    
# start_w_upper "FALSE" "TRUE"     "FALSE" "FALSE" "FALSE" "TRUE"       "FALSE" "TRUE"      "FALSE" "TRUE"     "FALSE"
# [,12]   [,13]   [,14]        [,15]   [,16]     [,17]  
# string        "of"    " "     "Technology" " - "   "Science" ""     
# start_w_upper "FALSE" "FALSE" "TRUE"       "FALSE" "TRUE"    "FALSE"
# 
# [[2]]
#              [,1]    [,2]    [,3]    [,4]   [,5]    [,6]   [,7]    [,8]   [,9]    [,10]  [,11]  
# string        ""      "Hello" " "     "Sam"  " ,"    "How"  " "     "Are"  " "     "You"  "?"    
# start_w_upper "FALSE" "TRUE"  "FALSE" "TRUE" "FALSE" "TRUE" "FALSE" "TRUE" "FALSE" "TRUE" "FALSE"
# 
# [[3]]
#              [,1]    [,2]          [,3]    [,4]       [,5]    [,6]    [,7]    [,8]   [,9]    [,10]        [,11]  
# string        ""      "Certificate" " - "   "Internet" " "     "and"   " "     "Web"  " "     "Technology" ""     
# start_w_upper "FALSE" "TRUE"        "FALSE" "TRUE"     "FALSE" "FALSE" "FALSE" "TRUE" "FALSE" "TRUE"       "FALSE"
```